# .htaccess URL rewrite not working Instead showing 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have clean URL's in my website using `.htaccess` I've tried a many procedures but none of them work, Here's my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ post/?post=$1 [NC,L]
```

the `.htaccess` file Is inside the `/post/` directory in my live Server.

The clean URL I wan't to achieve Is `http://example.com/news/post/latest-post/` instead of `http://example.com/news/post?post=latest-post`

PHP code:

```
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z_-]#i', '', $_GET['post']);
```

Thank You!

Comment: whats the name of your .php file?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/news/post/.htaccess` this code should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /news/post/

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ ?post=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: No you don't need any PHP code, just use `echo $_GET['post'];` to see the value in php code.

Comment: see updated rule, I think you have `/news/post/` folder not just `/post/` under `DocumentRoot`

Comment: inside the `/post/` i have `index.php` and `.htaccess` files

Comment: Full URL is `http://example.com/news/post/latest-post/` right? WHen you enter that what does it show?

Comment: it shows 404 error but it works with: `http://example.com/news/post?post=latest-post` and I'm using Godaddy hosting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74128/discussion-between-anubhava-and-arqetech).